# How to adjust Bulma Column height when one changes?

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, bulma

is it possible to make a column adjust its height when others change?
I have all columns at the same height using `flex` but when I change one of them dynamically, the others stay the same...
Any way to fix that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your flex direction is row than you can use align-items: stretch

```css
.fparent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: flex-start
}

.fparent>div {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="fparent">
  <div>Some content in first div Some content in first divSome content in first divSome content in first divSome content in first divSome content in first divSome content in first div
  </div>
  <div></div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a specific class to those components and add that class onChange using js and make sure to have the css for that class.
Happy Programming!